# Can't get Broadcom 43142 drivers to work after installation on 5420 Inspiron

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

I'm a complete newbie to ubuntu, I've already installed and reinstalled the Broadcom driver required done a numerous amount of steps on terminal but I can't seem to get wireless working. However, my wired connection seems to work just fine.

also I have tried to follow the instructions but get stuck at step number 2 when i get told "No package dpkg is available":

1) Download the file from the link

2) sudo yum install dpkg

3) mkdir BCM43142

4) dpkg-deb -x Downloads/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb BCM43142

5) cd BCM43142/usr/src/wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms-6.20.55.19~bdcom0602.0400.1000.0400/src/wl/sys

6) sudo yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers

7) vi wl_linux.c

8)
around line 43, remove the line

## include

9) save the file (:wq)

10) cd ../../..

11) make

Things should work, and you'll have a file called "wl.ko" in the current directory.

12) sudo yum remove broadcom-wl

13) sudo mkdir -p /lib/modules/3.5.2-3.fc17.x86_64/extra/wl

14) sudo cp wl.ko /lib/modules/3.5.2-3.fc17.x86_64/extra/wl

15) sudo depmod -a

16) sudo modprobe wl

I really need help :/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/869163/366454[Check this solution this may work](http://askubuntu.com/a/869163/366454)

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

YUM is the package manager for Red Hat and distros based on Red Hat. Ubuntu is based on Debian and uses the APT front-end for dpkg. If you are on a Ubuntu system, dpkg are already installed and working.

This is what you do:

1. [Download this file](http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb) (wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb)
2. Open your terminal and run this command:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms`
3. Navigate to your download folder (cd ~/Downloads) and run this command:

   `sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb`
4. Then run this command to load the modul:

   `sudo modprobe wl`

If you still are having problems, let us know and we will help you make it work!